# How to prove $\sinh^{-1} (\tan x)=\log \tan (\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{x}{2})$

Tags: trigonometry, hyperbolic-functions

Like the question says

How to prove $$\sinh^{-1} (\tan x)=\log \tan (\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{x}{2})$$
I have tried using many identity but in vain

For reference
$$\tanh ^{-1} x=\frac{1}{2} \log \frac{1+x}{1-x}$$
and $$\sinh^{-1} x=\log (x+\sqrt{x^2+1})$$

Comment: Same problem as with your [other question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1552782/97236). The right-hand side $\log\tan(\pi/4+x/2)$ is not defined (real) for all real $x$, but only on intervals. You should perhaps throw away the book you are getting those problem from? Or rather view the questions as: "For what $x$ is it true that ... ".

Comment: @mickep you seem to be a professional. I found a cover less book in the library I am a engineering student trying to master maths without a degree

Comment: There must be better books including problems on proving trigonometric identities. Your library probably has a lot of calculus books? I don't blame you, and more importantly, I don't want to discourage you. But you deserve a better book. (By the way, this means that all three answers below are wrong.)

Answer (score 1):

Putting $\tan x$ in place of $x$ in this formula $$\sinh^{-1} x=\log (x+\sqrt{x^2+1})$$ we have, 
$$\sinh^{-1} \tan x=\log (\tan x+\sqrt{(\tan x)^2+1})$$
$$=\log (\tan x+\sqrt{(\sec x)^2})$$
$$=\log (\tan x+ \sec x)$$
$$=\log (\frac{1+\sin x}{\cos x})$$
$$=\log \left[\frac{(\sin \frac{x}{2}+\cos \frac{x}{2})^2}{\cos^2 \frac{x}{2}-\sin^2 \frac{x}{2}}\right]$$
$$=\log \left[\frac{\sin \frac{x}{2}+\cos \frac{x}{2}}{\cos \frac{x}{2}-\sin \frac{x}{2}}\right]$$
$$=\log \left[\frac{1+\tan \frac{x}{2}}{1-\tan \frac{x}{2}}\right]$$
$$=\log \left[\frac{\tan \frac{\pi}{4}+\tan \frac{x}{2}}{1-\tan \frac{\pi}{4}\tan \frac{x}{2}}\right]$$
$$=\log \tan (\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{x}{2})$$

Hence proved.

Answer (score 1):

Notice, $$\sinh^{-1}(\tan x)=\log(\tan x+\sqrt{\tan^2 x+1})$$
$$=\log(\tan x+\sec x)$$$$=\log\left(\tan x+\frac{1}{\cos x}\right)$$
$$=\log\left(\frac{2\tan\frac{x}{2}}{1-\tan^2\frac{x}{2}}+\frac{1+\tan^2\frac{x}{2}}{1-\tan^2\frac{x}{2}}\right)$$
$$=\log\left(\frac{\left(1+\tan\frac{x}{2}\right)^2}{\left(1-\tan\frac{x}{2}\right)\left(1+\tan\frac{x}{2}\right)}\right)$$
$$=\log\left(\frac{1+\tan\frac{x}{2}}{1-\tan\frac{x}{2}}\right)$$
$$=\log\left(\frac{\tan\frac{\pi}{4}+\tan\frac{x}{2}}{1-\tan\frac{\pi}{4}\tan\frac{x}{2}}\right)$$
$$=\color{red}{\log\tan \left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{x}{2}\right)}$$

Answer (score 0):

We note
\begin{align*}
\sinh^{-1} (\tan x)=\log \tan (\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{x}{2})&\iff\tan x=\sinh\left(\log \tan (\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{x}{2})\right).
\end{align*}
The latter equality follows because
\begin{align*}
\sinh\left(\log \tan (\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{x}{2})\right)&=\frac{1}{2}\left(\tan (\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{x}{2})-\cot (\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{x}{2})\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\tan(x/2)+1}{1-\tan(x/2)}+\frac{\tan(x/2)-1}{1+\tan(x/2)}\right)\\
&=\frac{2\tan(x/2)}{1-\tan^2(x/2)}\\
&=\tan(x).
\end{align*}